# Long-term ball distribution in urns

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, markov-process, steady-state

> Suppose, we have $k$ urns each starting with $n$ balls (all balls are
>   of the same color). At each step, we draw balls from each urn, where
>   each ball could be drawn independently at random with probability $p$.
>   After we picked those balls. They are returned to the urns, with each ball
>   returned independently at random to one of the urns.

I'm interested in some directions to existing models, that describe the long-term behavior of such a system.

It resembles a random-walk on $n-$regular simplex, but the increments are also random and I don't see a way to model it as picking one ball at a time.

Let $X_i(t)$ - be a number of balls in urn $i$ at discrete time $t$, then
among others $$\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} \mathbb{P}\Big( \min X_i(t) \geq \frac{k-1}{k} n \Big) \geq ~?$$ is of interest.

Since, the model have a nice symmetries regarding the urns, I would expect
the answer to be $1$, probably for any number $\alpha < 1$, where above $\alpha = \frac{k-1}{k}$. Is this true?

Comment: At a particular step, how many balls are drawn?

Comment: Each ball has a probability $p$ to be drawn. So if $p=0.2$, than on average one fifth of balls are drawn.

Comment: I would have thought after large $t$, the distribution would be close to that of putting each of the $nk$ balls into an urn at random, so for an individual urn the number of balls would have a distribution close to binomial with parameters $nk$ and $\frac1k$, so with mean $n$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{\frac{k-1}{k}n}$.  Unless $k$ is very small, I do not see why your limit would be anywhere near $1$, and even then I would have thought the limit has to be strictly less than $1$ for all $k>1$

Comment: @Henry, so, you are saying ignore what happened, stop the timer and suppose all balls were just randomly dropped. The assumption is, that each ball was drawn at least once?

Comment: In the limit, the probability each ball has been selected at least once seems to be $1$